# War, Pray and Learn

Tags: tefilla, sources-mekorot, midrash, army-military-war

The Medrash Rabbah and the Yalkut relate that during the war against Midyon, for every one that went out to battle there was a designated person whose task it was to pray and learn for him. Where in the *Medrash Rabbah* and *Yalkut* does it say that?

Rav Chaim Kanievsky pointed out that Dovid HaMelech, instituted the practice, that for every individual who was in combat, there was another person selected for the specific task of being mispalleil and learning for him. What source did Rav Chaim get this from?

Comment: Where did you see this Rav Chaim

Comment: http://matzav.com/the-shmira-project-protect-an-israeli-soldier

Comment: How do you know your first sentence is even true?

Answer (score 2):

[Medrash Rabah Parshas Matos](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=24625&st=&pgnum=148&hilite=) is the source of a designated person praying for every one that went to war. שהיו נמסרות זוגות זה לזה

Comment: I am not sure how it is possible that Dovid HaMelech instituted this as the Milchemes Midyan was before the time of King David.

Comment: Where in Parshas Matos does it say this (i.e. Perek 22, Posuk __)?

Comment: I see no mention of individually designated people on that page. (If I'm missing it please identify it more precisely.)

Comment: I meant, where in Medrash Rabah Parshas Matos does it say that there was a designated person praying for every one that went to war? (i.e. Perek 22, Posuk__?)

Comment: Is that phrase you edited in an answer to my question? I don't see how it does so. In fact, the commentary on the page you linked to explicitly explains it otherwise.

Comment: Gershon, where in the Yalkut does it say this (i.e. Parshas Matos, Perek__, Posuk__)?

Comment: The link provided seems to stating the requested answer.  There is a shi'ta that Moshe sent 3000 from every tribe, one "caretaker" and one "prayer" for every "fighter".  The proof is the "nimsar" quote.  זוגות זה לזה implies that they were literally paired up 1:1, and the commentary on the bottom of the page further elucidates that this is like  "regular armies" where two people are paired up to look after each other.

Answer (score 0):

Matos chapter 31 sentence 4. a thousand from a tribe a thousand from a tribe. Verse 5, total of 12,000 to fight.
[Torah Attitude: Parashas Mattos: The Secret Army](http://www.shemayisrael.com/parsha/kahn/archives/matos68.htm)

Summary

> G'd instructed Moses to take revenge only against the Midianites and
>   not against the Moabites. For every thousand from the tribes of Israel
>   that went into the army, another thousand went into the study halls to
>   battle our enemies. The physical battlefield is only a facade. The
>   real battle takes place in the house of study and prayer where the
>   soldiers are those who study Torah and pray to G'd. Jacob's "sword"
>   refers to the study of Torah, and the "bow" refers to the words of
>   prayer. The power of prayer depends on sincerity and truth. Our secret
>   army is our Torah scholars and Yeshiva students.

Thus every one in each tribe who went to war was matched by someone who learned for the war. It does not mean that each person had a specific "partner" but that the numbers from each tribe matched.

Comment: "Where in the Medrash Rabbah and Yalkut does it say that?"

Comment: Do you see any indication that each person had a designated individual praying/learning on his behalf, as asked by the question?